# Caffe classifocation.cpp always returns 100% probability

Tags: c++, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to use Caffe c++ [classification](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/cpp_classification.html) example (here is the [code](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/cpp_classification/classification.cpp)) to classify image with handwritten digit (I train my model on MNIST database), but it always returns probabilities like

```
[0, 0, 0, 1.000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]  (1.000 can be on different position)
```

even if image has no number on it. I think it should be something like

```
[0.01, 0.043, ... 0.9834, ... ]
```

Also, for example for '9', it's always predicts wrong number.
The only one thing I change in classification.cpp is that I'm always using CPU

```
//#ifdef CPU_ONLY    
  Caffe::set_mode(Caffe::CPU); // <----- always CPU
//#else
//  Caffe::set_mode(Caffe::GPU);
//#endif
```

This is how my deploy.prototxt looks like

```
name: "LeNet"
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "ImageData"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  image_data_param {
    source: "D:\\caffe-windows\\examples\\mnist\\test\\file_list.txt"
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 20
    kernel_size: 5
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "pool1"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "pool1"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool1"
  top: "conv2"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 50
    kernel_size: 5
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "pool2"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "pool2"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "ip1"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "pool2"
  top: "ip1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 500
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "ip1"
  top: "ip1"
}
layer {
  name: "ip2"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "ip1"
  top: "ip2"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 10
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "Softmax"
  bottom: "ip2"
  top: "loss"
}
```

file_list.txt is

```
D:\caffe-windows\examples\mnist\test\test1.jpg 0
```

And tests1.jpg is something like this

[image]

(black&white 28*28 image saved in paint, I have tried different sizes but it doesn't matter, Preprocces() resizes it anyway)

To train network I use [this](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/mnist.html) tutorial, here is [prototxt](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/mnist/lenet_train_test.prototxt)

So why it predicts wrong digits and alway with 100% probability?

(I'm using windows 7, VS13)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your "ImageData" layer, you should normalize your test1.jpg data from [0, 255] to [0, 1] by "scale" to keep the consistency of preprocess manner between training and test like the following:

```
image_data_param {
    source: "D:\\caffe-windows\\examples\\mnist\\test\\file_list.txt"
    scale: 0.00390625
  }
```